# How to split a text file into 2 parts based on 3 (or more) newlines in bash

Tags: bash, split, text-files

I have a simple text file and I **want to split it into 2 parts
whenever I see 3 (or more) consecutive new lines**. For example:

```
Fiona Gallagher
Frank Gallagher
Sheila Jackson



Dominique Winslow
Kermit
```

Should create 2 text files:

```
Fiona Gallagher
Frank Gallagher
Sheila Jackson
```

and

```
Dominique Winslow
Kermit
```

Though similar posts in SO address the problem of splitting text files into 2 parts ([this PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843499/how-to-split-a-text-block-into-2-strings-in-php), [this C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310684/how-to-split-a-text-file-into-multiple-files), [and this Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472755/java-how-to-separate-a-text-file-to-files-by-separator-string)) I could not find a solution in bash. It seems reasonable enough that a neat bash solution is out there somewhere (?).
Thanks!

Comment: Are you against common GNU commands, like `csplit`?

Comment: Ideally a mixture of grep, sed, cat and awk is best, but please post any other solution too.

Comment: That is not pure bash, so you might want to put specifically that in the question.

Comment: @kabanus could you re-post your csplit solution? I think there is a possible workaround with csplit.

Comment: I did, hope it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the request of OP, a `csplit` solution that only works with 2 consecutive `\n\n` or more.

---

The easiest way would be to use the GNU `csplit` which any modern `bash` system has. Suppose `bla` contains:

```
Fiona Gallagher
Frank Gallagher
Sheila Jackson

Dominique Winslow
Kermit






a
v
b
```

then

```
csplit --suppress-matched -z bla "/^$/" '{*}'
```

will do what you want, creating

```
>cat xx00 
Fiona Gallagher
Frank Gallagher
Sheila Jackson
>cat xx01
Dominique Winslow
Kermit
>cat xx02
a
v
b
```

You can change the `xx` to any prefix using `-f` or `--prefix=`. The `--suppress-matched` makes sure the thing you split on (empty lines) will not be output and `-z` ensures consecutive empty lines do not form empty files. `{*}` Means split as many times as possible.

Comment: can you enforce a minimum of 3 consecutive newlines?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Ah, no sorry. I'll remove the answer. I thought it said 2.

Comment: Restored the answer as requested.